# Implement AdWhirl + iAD

Tags: iphone, ios, iad, adwhirl

Hello Everybody,
                 is this possible to use Ad Whirl with iAd in IOS application? i am unable to find any tutorial regarding this? if anybody know about this, please reply with a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this http://www.raywenderlich.com/2011/11/24/how-to-integrate-adwhirl-into-a-cocos2d-game/

Hope the Link helps You.

Note if you are working on a non-Cocos2d look at the comments there is a comment for non cocos2d users

Cheer.